# save username from login to another form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, authentication

I need to save the user name in a sql table, example: an user
  put it's user name and password in the login, then, in other form must
  send some data in textboxes to another user, how can I save the username?
  I'm working in a website with visual studio 2008, c sharp and sql server 2005, thanks
  in advance.

this is my code in login and I have to pass the user name to the 2nd form

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    ClPersona login = new ClPersona();
    bool isAuthenticated = login.sqlLogin1((txtUsuario.Text), (txtPassword.Text));
    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        //prueba para sesion
        Session["sesionicontrol"] = login.NombreUsuario;
        Response.Redirect("../MENU/menu1.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Is that asp webform or asp.net mvc?

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins is asp.net mvc, thanks.

Comment: Make it a session variable, you should be able to retrieve it later.

Comment: @DanielA.White I tryied to save the username as a session, or copy the name of the login form to the 2nd form, as a label not visible, but I'm stuck, I don´t know how to do it.

Comment: @Alex I edited my question, how can I pass the user name to the 2nd form? thanks in advance.

Comment: The source code provided ain't Asp.Net MVC but Asp.Net Webform, I am confused with your question.

Comment: Just read session["sesionicontrol"] in the other form. Your code doesn't look like MVC ...

Comment: What if you attach to DB from login window and compare the password - if ok - then form 2 could use the pass from DB if not - retry enter password in form1 (If I understand you question correctly)

Comment: sorry it was webform, I was wrong, how can I read the ["sesionicontrol"] in a label??? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop a label on your target form like this:

```
<asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="Label"></asp:label>
```

Go to code behind of the target page find method `Page_Load` and add following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = (string) Session["sesionicontrol"];
    }
```

This will read the value of `login.NombreUsuario` hich was saved previously into `Session["sesionicontrol"]` and display it in label.

Assuptions I made are that:

1. `login.NombreUsuario` - contains the data you are reffering as user name - and that's what you want to pass along.
2. it is of type `string`.

---

Generally `Session` privides a dictionary to save any named objects. They are shared between all pages inside current session. You can use session to pass some data across pages like this:

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["SomeKey"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx"); 
    }
```

This saves the value you have just entered in `TextBox` into session.

**WebForm2.aspx**

```
<asp:label ID="Label1" runat="server" text="Label"></asp:label>
```

**WebForm2.sapx.cs**

```
public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = (string) Session["someKey"];
    }
}
```

This fetches the values you have stored in previous page uner key `SomeKey` and sets it to `Label` before the page gets rendered. You see the text you have entered on the forst page.

Comment: yes you are rigth, login.NombreUsuario have the date of the user name ando the type is string, what I need is pass that username to the second form,but I can't, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a question, if I put a user name in the login I can see it in the 2nd form but I can´t save it, because I get this error: "the name of (username) is not valid in this context"

Comment: Dear @suely I would suggest you create another question and post your code snippet there. It is difficult to give you an answer without having more information.